# Get current cell from =choose functions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell with a choose function

```
=CHOOSE(A3;Food!$J$2;Food!$K$2;Food!$L$2;Food!$M$2;Food!$N$2;Food!$O$2;Food!$P$2;Food!$Q$2;Food!$R$2;Food!$S$2;Food!$T$2;Food!$U$2;Food!$V$2;Food!$W$2;Food!$X$2;Food!$Y$2;Food!$Z$2;Food!$AA$2;Food!$AB$2;Food!$AC$2;Food!$AD$2;Food!$AE$2;Food!$AF$2;Food!$AG$2;Food!$AH$2;Food!$AI$2;Food!$AJ$2;Food!$AK$2;Food!$AL$2;Food!$AM$2;)
```

In the other cell I want to receive the address of the cell in which the choose function are now referring

if index is `1` I want to get `Food!$J$2`, or if index is `3` I want to get `Food!$L$2` and so on

How I can solve this problem with vba?

Comment: By using `Select Case`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout no, I'm interesting in how to substring cell adress from this formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order of the items you require:

**First** get the cell address and **then** get the contents.  So in A4 enter:

```
=CHOOSE(A3,"Food!$J$2","Food!$K$2","Food!$L$2","Food!$M$2","Food!$N$2","Food!$O$2","Food!$P$2","Food!$Q$2","Food!$R$2","Food!$S$2","Food!$T$2","Food!$U$2","Food!$V$2","Food!$W$2","Food!$X$2","Food!$Y$2","Food!$Z$2","Food!$AA$2","Food!$AB$2","Food!$AC$2","Food!$AD$2","Food!$AE$2","Food!$AF$2","Food!$AG$2","Food!$AH$2","Food!$AI$2","Food!$AJ$2","Food!$AK$2","Food!$AL$2","Food!$AM$2")
```

and in A5 enter:

```
=INDIRECT(A4)
```

and if you really require VBA use somthing like:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String, Indx As Long
    s = Range("A4").Formula
    ary = Split(s, ",")
    Indx = Range("A3")
    MsgBox ary(Indx)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are doing this? Why don't you just:

```
=INDEX(Food!$J$2:$AM$2;1;A3)
```

?

Comment: I'm new in excel, thank you for advice! But still, how to get an adress from the array?